# How to test angular multi select dropdown using protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, multi-select

I am using angular-multi-select dropdown from https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select. Now i want to write test cases in protractor.

```
<div ng-show="!attribute.isMultivalued && page != 'view'" 
     class="select-group" 
     multi-select 
     input-model="typesDataDup"
     output-model="attribute.types"
     button-label="typeName"         
     item-label="typeName" 
     tick-property="ticked" 
     selection-mode="single"
     helper-elements="filter"
     is-disabled = "page == 'view'">
</div>
```

I am unable to send data using model because here we don't mention ng-model.

Could anyone help me out in writing test case for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this i took css help. I had checked css in inspect element then i got this solution

```
element.all(by.buttonText('None selected')).then(function(items) {
   items[1].click();
}); 
element.all(by.model('inputLabel.labelFilter')).then(function(items) {
   items[1].sendKeys(protractor.Key.DOWN+protractor.Key.DOWN);
});
ptor.sleep(200);
element.all(by.css('.multiSelectFocus')).then(function(items) {
   items[0].click();
});
```

Here i am selecting particular option using DOWN key

Answer (score 5):

You can rely on other attributes and use [`by.css`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) to find the element. For example:

```
element(by.css('div.select-group'))
```

or

```
element(by.css('div[multi-select]'))
```

As far as I see from the [`angular-multi-select` source code](https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select/blob/master/angular-multi-select.js), select options are represented with button elements. Use `element.all()` to find all buttons inside and click the desired one, for instance, `Select All`:

```
element.all(by.css('div[multi-select] button')).then(function(options) {
    options.forEach(function(option) {
        option.getText().then(function(text) {
            if (text.indexOf("Select All") != -1) {
                option.click();
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @alecexe. Yes but it can't select particular option using this code

Comment: @AnushaNilapu that's ok, it was an interesting challenge. I'll leave it here in case it would help somebody in the future. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: yeah it may help others